I'm writing a simple calculator using Flex and Bison, but I keep encountering errors like missing library, unresolved reference
%option noyywrap

%{

#include "calculator.tab.h"

int yyerror(const char *);
%}

%%

[ \t]              
[0-9]+             { yylval = atoi(yytext); return NUMBER; }
"+"                { return ADD; }
"*"                { return MUL; }
"^"                { return EXPONENT; }
"("                { return LPAREN; }
")"                { return RPAREN; }
\n                 { return 0; } 
.                  { yyerror("Invalid character"); }

%%



This is my flex code.
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
%}

%token NUMBER ADD MUL EXPONENT LPAREN RPAREN
%left ADD
%left MUL
%left EXPONENT

%%

input: 
     | input line
     ;

line: expr { printf("Result: %d\n", $1); }
    ;

expr: NUMBER
    | expr ADD expr      { $$ = $1 + $3; }
    | expr MUL expr     { $$ = $1 * $3; }
    | expr EXPONENT expr  { $$ = power($1, $3); }
    | LPAREN expr RPAREN  { $$ = $2; }
    ;

%%

int power(int base, int exp) {
    int result = 1;
    for (; exp > 0; --exp) {
        result *= base;
    }
    return result;
}

int yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", s);
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    yyparse();
    return 0;
}


This is my bison code.
I was getting the error "cannot find -lfl", so I did some digging and found a solution to use noyywrap in the code. After that, I'm getting the following error:
C:\Users\paart\AppData\Local\Temp\cci2ZuAz.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to `yylval'
C:\Users\paart\AppData\Local\Temp\cci2ZuAz.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to `yyerror'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I do have both programs installed. I also tried compiling and directly linking the libfl.a file,
gcc lex.yy.c -o main -l'C:\GnuWin32\lib' -lfl

also tried libfl.a

But I'm getting the same error again, cannot find lfl/libfl.a
How can I resolve this?
I tried to compile lex and bison files, but I got several errors. I tried solving but no luck.

C:\GnuWin32\lib doesn't look like a library. Do you want to add library folder? Try -L instead of -l.

@Gerhardh I changed it but I got another error, unresolved reference
C:\Users\paart\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0OA6IE.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x1b1): undefined reference to yylval' C:\Users\paart\AppData\Local\Temp\cc0OA6IE.o:lex.yy.c:(.text+0x203): undefined reference to yyerror'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Does lex.yy.c contain these functions from your bison code? I am not familiar with lex/bison. Do you have 2 C files created from these files or only one?

You aren’t linking the compiled .y file. The WinMain error means a wrong compiler or linker flag for a command line tool, but don’t ask me which,

Use -ll instead of -lfl. At some point flex changed the name of their library (to the library name the original lex used).

My (current) flex on Linux uses libfl, no libl in sight. The Fedora 40 package has no libraries.
